# fluent ffmpeg size output option not working

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Summary: I'm trying to limit output to 3mb, `.outputOptions('-fs 3000000')` isn't working for me, the file is coming back with a size of `119260428` or 119mb.

Here is the code to try for yourself, all you need is a `test.mp3` large enough that the resulting `testoutput.ogg` is > 3mb:

```
var ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
var command = ffmpeg();

var convertToOGG = function(){
  var fileName = 'test.mp3'

  ffmpeg.ffprobe(fileName, function(err, metadata) {
    command
      .input(fileName)
      .inputFormat("mp3")
      .audioChannels(1)
      .outputOptions('-fs', 3000000)
      .output('testoutput.ogg')
      .on("progress", function(progress) {
        console.log("Processing: " + progress.timemark);
      })
      .on("error", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("Cannot process video: " + err.message);
      })
      .on("end", function(stdout, stderr) {
        ffmpeg.ffprobe('testoutput.ogg', function(err,metadata){
          if(metadata.format.size >= 3000000){

            console.log("didn't work")
          } 
        })
      })
    .run();
  });
};

convertToOGG();
```

Per the [fluent-ffmpeg documentation](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) you should be able to use a ffmpeg command in an output option: `outputOption()`

> This method allows passing any output-related option to ffmpeg. You can call it with a single argument to pass a single option, optionnaly
>   with a space-separated parameter:

```
/* Single option */
ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi').outputOptions('-someOption');
```

[and in FFMPEG's documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> -fs limit_size (output) Set the file size limit, expressed in bytes. No further chunk of bytes is written after the limit is exceeded. The
>   size of the output file is slightly more than the requested file size.

It's giving me no errors, just seemingly ignoring the file size limit of 99mb and outputting a 119.3mb file.

Edit - Looks like `-fs 3000000` is working for mp3 to wav, but still wont do mp3 to ogg.  This is the output from running the command in terminal:

```
✗ ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -fs 3000000 testoutput.ogg
ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fc6a4000000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'test.mp3':
  Metadata:
    lyrics-eng      : xxx
    title           : xxx
    artist          : xxx
    album_artist    : xxx
    album           : xxx
    genre           : xxx
  Duration: 03:27:28.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 540x360, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Array
      comment         : Cover (front)
[swscaler @ 0x7fc6a4808800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[ogg @ 0x7fc6a3815800] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, ogg, to 'testoutput.ogg':
  Metadata:
    lyrics-eng      : xxx
    title           : xxx
    artist          : xxx
    album_artist    : xxx
    album           : xxx
    genre           : xxx
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: theora (libtheora), yuv444p, 540x360, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Array
      DESCRIPTION     : Cover (front)
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libtheora
      lyrics-eng      : xxx
      artist          : xxx
      ALBUMARTIST     : xxx
      album           : xxx
      genre           : xxx
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libvorbis
      lyrics-eng      : xxx
      title           : xxx
      artist          : xxx
      ALBUMARTIST     : xxx
      album           : xxx
      genre           : xxx
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> theora (libtheora))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=  116465kB time=03:27:28.71 bitrate=  76.6kbits/s speed=61.2x
video:9kB audio:114907kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:6kB muxing overhead: 1.347787%
```

Comment: Execute the same `ffmpeg` command directly in the console and post the complete output please.

Comment: Ah interesting `-fs 3000000` limited the output to 3mb when it was transcoding to `.wav` but is not working on `.ogg`.  I have been assuming it worked for both.

Comment: For me it works on OGG too. Can you try it with `-map 0:a` before `-fs` to take just the audio without the cover image? It tries to encode the cover image at **90k fps**! That seems a bit excessive and might explain the huge file size :)

Comment: YES!  Thank you!!  add that as an answer and collect the bounty!

Comment: Can you share the source mp3? This looks like a bug in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: http://traffic.libsyn.com/joeroganexp/p897.mp3?dest-id=19997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source `mp3` contains a cover image. Attempting to transcode the source file to `ogg` results in an unusually high framerate for the video stream.

There's a problem with the framerate estimation: `90k fps` resembles the stream timebase value:

```
[ogg @ 0x7fc6a3815800] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
[...]
Stream #0:0: Video: theora (libtheora), yuv444p, 540x360, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

This could be caused by a problem with the source file, a bug in `ffmpeg` or maybe both.

A quick solution is to ignore the cover image using either `-map 0:a` or `-vn`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked but if you notice the video stream output is only 9kb whereas the audio is close to 115MB. My first thought was that the cover stream was reported by the muxer as part of the audio, but if so, what's the 9kb?

Comment: @Mulvya That's why I asked for the source file. My first thought was a problem in the muxer, although the reported muxing overhead is low.

Comment: Replied with the source file above.  Thanks once again!

Comment: @Mulvya I see a lot of `Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue ... forcing output` messages.