# How to reduce video size using node ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

I'm using following npm package in NodeJS application.
What I need to do is reduce the size of videos.
My videos are in mp4 format.
Is there any way to reduce size of those videos using node-ffmpeg ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

There are not good answers or samples. I followed this code some steps and idea, but no good. [fluent ffmpeg size output option not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669262/fluent-ffmpeg-size-output-option-not-working)

In normal ffmpeg, we can do like this.

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfilename> -s 640x480 -b:v 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy <outputfilename>
```

How can we do the same in NodeJS ?

Please help me on this.
any sample code or idea is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing video size with same format and reducing frame size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490154/reducing-video-size-with-same-format-and-reducing-frame-size)

Comment: @OrangeDog Oh, thanks buddy. I think that's really basic. Like only executing some terminal command. I though a lot of this npm module. :-( Anyway, thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). That's all that the node modules do.

e.g.

```
child_process.execFile('ffmpeg', [
    '-i', inputfilename,
    '-s', '640x480',
    '-b:v', '512k',
    '-c:v', 'mpeg1video',
    '-c:a', 'copy',
    outputfilename
], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // ...
})
```

I would avoid using any modules as they obfuscate what commands they're actually running, and if you want to do something more advanced that they haven't added code for then you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is helpful to me. I will try to use this. Better than nothing...... you are so helpful. :-)

Comment: Can't we use like this ? new ffmpeg('/path/to/your_movie.avi'); And create an object and use ?

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva I don't know, I've never used any of these modules. If you really want to then consult their documentation.